# Aligning two elements, one left and the other right

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm experimenting with TailwindCSS for the first time and I'm trying to customize the table in the last row of the temple below.

https://www.tailwindtoolbox.com/templates/admin-template-demo.php

I'd like to add a circle in the right-hand side of the header. Something like

[image]

I have tried different solutions and the one that gets closer to what I want is

```
  <div class="border-b-2 rounded-tl-lg rounded-tr-lg p-2">
      <h5 class="uppercase"><%= host.name %></h5>
      <span class="rounded-full px-2 py-2 float-right"></span>
    </div>
```

Which places the green dot over the lower border. Clearly `float-right` isn't the right approach but I can't figure out a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use a `<span>` use a `<div>` instead as a `<span>` requires content. You can then float the `<h5>` left and the 'circle' right, but you will need to add the `clearfix` to the parent div.

Also, instead of adding the classes `px-2` you can just define the height using the class `h-*` this is the same with the width: `w-*`. I set a background-color of green aswell using the class `bg-green`.

```
<div class="border-b-2 rounded-tl-lg rounded-tr-lg p-2 clearfix">
    <h5 class="uppercase float-left"><%= host.name %></h5>
    <div class="rounded-full h-3 w-3 circle bg-green float-right"></div>
</div>
```

see my codepen here: https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/jdRbQM

alternatively you can use `flex`:

```
<div class="border-b-2 rounded-tl-lg rounded-tr-lg p-2 flex">
    <h5 class="uppercase flex-1 text-center"><%= host.name %></h5>
    <div class="rounded-full h-3 w-3 circle bg-green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the second and it's work.. so upvoted.